# Any way to keep progress bars in Powershell without crippling performance?

Tags: powershell

Is there any user made function that can replace the progress bar? I have a script that downloads and extracts a zip, but having the progress bars enabled `$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'` results in the process taking quite literally 50 times as long as if they are disabled with `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

However, I'd really like to have progress bars. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You could run your download code as a job. Then check on the status of the job using `Write-Progress`. However, if the job is fast, what's the point of checking progress?

Comment: To inform the end user that the download is proceeding normally, this script is to be used by others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Invoke-WebRequest` for downloading a file with the default progress preference, it will provide a constant byte stream update, which crushes performance. You can run the command as a job and provide the progress of the bytes downloaded at an interval of your choice.

```
$uri = 'https://host.domain.com/myfile'
$sb = {
          $progresspreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $using:uri -Outfile 'c:\temp\file.txt'
}
Start-Job -Name 'Download' -ScriptBlock $sb
while ((Get-Job -Name 'Download').State -eq 'Running') {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloaded Bytes" -CurrentOperation $((Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\file.txt').Length)
    sleep 1
}
```

Comment: I only get an indication that the job started, no progress. https://imgur.com/a/sryl1lf

Comment: If you want the output of a job, you will need to use `Receive-Job -Name 'Download'` or `Receive-Job -Name 'Download' -Keep` if you want to retrieve the job results beyond the first retrieval. You can store the result in a variable as well.

Comment: You need to make sure the `$progresspreference` is set to `Continue` on your system. The script block `$sb` has its own scope (its own `$progresspreference`) and does not impact your session.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download files with the progress bars and not take a performance hit in the process, then **[Start-BitsTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer)** from the **BitsTransfer** module is what you want to use.

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $using:uri -Destination 'c:\temp\file.txt'
```

For file transfers, **[Start-BitsTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer)** is vastly superior to **Invoke-WebRequest**. Once you make the switch, you'll never looked back. You still get the progress bars, unless using asynchronous mode, but the performance hit is negligible since the transfer is taking place in the background using the Windows BITS service. Plus, you get all the benefits of the BITS service such as suspend/pause background transfers, select transfer priority/policy policy, resumed downloads across system reboots, use stored credentials from the Windows Credential Manager.

Additionally, the **-Source** and **-Destination** parameters work with *any combination* of the following:

- Local paths
- Remote file share paths
- URI paths

NOTE: The **BitsTransfer** module was first available in Windows Powershell 3.0 on Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 and newer.

Comment: The problem with Bits is that other Bits jobs can prevent the transfer from happening.